# Mostrar productos que pertenecen a una categoría con tablas relacionales MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo 3 tablas

```
Tabla 1 - productos
idProducto Nombre

Tabla 2 - categorias
idCategoria Nombre

Tabla 3 - categoriasproductos
idCategoriaProducto idProducto idCategoria
```

Cada producto pertenece, AL MENOS, a una categoría y mi objetivo es mostrar los productos que UNÍCAMENTE pertenecen a x categoría. Pero como no tengo ni pajolera idea pues me está mostrando de todo.. si alguien me hiciera el favor de echarme un cable.. y en cuanto pueda iré aprendiendo de una forma más ordenada.

Comment: nos muestras por favor que consulta has tratado de hacer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para mostrar los productos filtrados por una categoria lo que necesitas hacer es (en terminos de conjuntos) intersectar las tablas `Producto` y `CategoriasProductos` por el campo en común que tienen ambas tablas y agregar el filtro de la `categoría` en particular que deseas. Esto se puede hacer de varias formas pero lo correcto seria usar la funcionalidad JOIN del motor de datos.

```
SELECT 
    idProducto, Nombre
FROM Producto P
INNER JOIN categoriasproductos C ON P.idProducto=C.idProducto
WHERE C.idCategoria = [Id Categoria]
```

Te recomendaría leer algún manual y hacer ejercicios de intersecciones de tablas para que mejores tus habilidades ya que esta funcionalidad es algo básico para el manejo de bases de datos.

EN este enlace puedes encontrar una explicación y ejemplos
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

[image: Tipos de JOIN]

Comment: Buenas nerdcoder!:

Muchas gracias también por tu aportación. Finalmente tu sugerencia parece estar cumpliendo mis necesidades. La sentencia la tuve que modificar un poquitín nada más, pero es lo que has comentado:

SELECT p.* FROM Productos P INNER JOIN categoriasproductos C ON P.idProducto=C.idProducto WHERE idCategoria = "identificador";

Muchas gracias!!!